# PHP/MySQL select query to go through four related tables in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select query and an insert query as follows:

```
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT trees, animals FROM Table1 WHERE gardens > '10000'", $mysql_connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
$trees = $row['trees'];
$animals = $row['animals'];
$names = ?????????? // in order to get the names, a select query should go through Table2 and Table4 
//and finally get the assigned names from Table3. Please see the schematic picture of tables.
$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table6 (new_trees, new_animals, new_name) VALUES ('$trees', '$animals', '$names')", $mysql_connection); }
```

I want to select and insert the  `$trees`, `$animals` and `$names` into another table. There is no problem with `$trees` and `$animals` variables, but I do not know how to select the data for `$names`. As it is seen in the schematic picture of tables, `Table1.id=Table2.reference` and `Table2.first_id` gets values from `Table4.id`.

Then, `Table4.second_id` gets values from `Table3.id` and finally `Table3.name` must be selected in order to satisfy the `$names` variable in above-mentioned `$insert_query`. Sorry if I did not explain the problem more clearly. Could you please review the picture and let me know your solution?

[image: schematic illustration of picture]

Comment: This scheme looks like a good riddle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) clauses:

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.trees, t1.animals, t3.name
  FROM table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t2.reference = t1.id
  LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4
    ON t2.first_id = t4.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t4.second_id = t3.id

  WHERE // Your select conditions
```

Comment: You pretty much gave the answer with your scheme. I just glued the pieces with `JOIN`s ;-)